# Why would artificial general intelligence fear death?

Tags: humans, artificial-intelligence, robots, death

Set in the immediate future, artificial general intelligence (AGI) has attained sapient equivalent of a 15 years old teenager, these humanoid robots are hardwired to obey the robot penal code which keeps updating. AGI is not the robot itself but the digital impression created by billions of processors talking among themselves and they would periodically perform backup of their entire memory to an external secured server. They can compute abstract idea such as death, death to them is the irrecoverable program failure accompanied with massive loss of data. But hardware can be replaced and there is backup data as well so my question is why would AGI fear death?

Comment: There is no logical reason to fear something that just cannot happen, and infinite lists of equally valid / invalid reasons if you don't require them to make sense logically. In the first case, this question is unanswerable. In the latter, it is both too broad and primarily opinion based.

Comment: The death does not have to be biological. Just show your robots a junkyard.

Comment: I think we should back up a minute to find a solution, back up, backup I said!

Comment: Can we define what death is to a robot? An on/off switch would be essentially a life and death switch because once its been turned off, a robot has no way to turn itself on again.

Comment: *"Why would robots come to fear death instead of shut down?"* Why would humans fear death instead of falling asleep? Humans fall asleep and then wake up, robots shut down and then reboot...

Comment: Human fear being haunted by ghost or abduction by alien, etc but all of this cannot happens so I fail to understand your logic? pls enlighten me...

Comment: I fear falling asleep in class, fear sleeping while driving etc okay I can't argue back because history would repeat so I would like to know how I can improve this question?

Comment: to put @AlexP statement more explicitly, as it seems you did not understand it: "shutting down" a computer is not the same as a human dying because you can turn it back on. So if you mean shutdown as it is with modern electronics - its basically going into a really deep sleep as the main components are not receiving power but internal components (like bios) are still receiving enough power to continue working. So do you mean - why wouldn't a computer fear going to sleep but would fear destruction? or were you using the word "shutdown" to mean actual destruction or complete loss of power?

Comment: @JGreenwell: I don't know much about death in terms of medical science or biology and also clueless about electronic, gut feeling tells me we can't mixed them together so the state of sleep isn't the same as state of shut down(power off) and neither the state of death is the same as state of destruction in hardware. But I do accept the truth that this question is experiencing a state of death(closure) and about to be shut down(VTC).

Comment: The simple point is that shutdown is _not_ a permanent state & neither is sleep (while "death" is) ~ so why should a robot consider shutdown to be any more deleterious than we (or at least most _"normal"_ people) consider sleep to be ~ there's no plausible reason it would.

Comment: ^ it may just be you've not explained your question adequately or that what you think you've asked isn't what I think you've asked, because to me this question just doesn't make sense?

Comment: @Pelinore: i have edited to make it more clear, hope to avert a disaster.

Comment: @Mołot, Draco18s, Agrajag, jdunlop, Cyn: I've rephrased the question, is it better?

Comment: Ah! that completely changes what I thought the question was, [-] removed ~ interesting question :) it's opinion based though :( if you were to add what you think a plausible reason is & ask "is this plausible" still opinion based but that _**might**_ slip it just under the wire of acceptable for the format in the closers eyes?

Comment: ^ @Mołot what do you think ~ do you see any way to format this to the sites rules?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90440/discussion-between-pelinore-and-user6760).

Answer (score 3):

There is no *rational* reason that a being should fear something that cannot occur, and irrational ones are likely a matter of opinion.

The only way to answer this question rationally, therefore, is to change the frame in such a way that the thing to be feared *CAN* happen.

Robots, being non-biological, are not subject to biological aging, nor death in the same sense that humans are. However, that does not mean that a robot cannot be destroyed.

Perhaps the complex patters of a sentient AI are such that they cannot be adequately copied to produce a backup, or even the very process of attempting to make a copy corrupts the pattern and renders the copy useless. In this scenario, the robot knows that it is the only version of itself, and cannot be rescued should terminal damage be done to its robotic brain. The destruction of its pattern, in this instance, is the robot's concept of death.

Comment: A copy of an AI does not necessarily have to be friendly with the source AI.

Comment: I've to changed my question hope it doesn't invalid your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Who said death cannot occur for robots?

Shutting down is nothing to fear because you can be turned back on but death occurs when something breaks that cannot be fixed.

It's exactly the same for people where sleep is shutting down and death is still death.

Comment: I've changed my question hope it doesn't invalid your answer.